# FWD trike steering

Tags: wheels, steering

I have a question about reverse trikes like this:

[image]

Suppose the reverse trike in the photo is FWD, has two individually powered front wheels and has no differential. When the right wheel is driven faster than the left, will both wheels point to the left and the vehicle turn left with little or no skidding? Or will the angle of the front wheels stay the same and the vehicle turn left by skidding? Or something else completely different?

Comment: If the front wheels are individually powered, why would there be a differential fitted?

Comment: @SolarMike No, let's assume there's no differential. Just a simple four bar Ackerman linkage.

Comment: If front wheels are individually powered it would most likely introduce torque steer if not powered the same. The outside tire in a turn will have to turn faster, given it travels a larger arc to get to the same place.

Comment: Yep, that'd be "voluntary" torque steer.

Like with all motor vehicles, making a trike like that FWD would be a pretty dumb idea.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 But could the steering angle of the resultant torque steering be predictable? If so, wouldn't it be a useful means for power steering as the steering effect is sent back to the steering column?

Comment: @JohnM. - It could possibly be done this way, however, it seems like you're trying to solve a problem which doesn't exist and in doing so, are creating other problems which would have to be overcome. How would the rider tell the machine which way they want to turn if the trike is putting torque back through the system by which the turning is being done in the first place? You'd be causing a feedback loop in the system, one which the rider would be fighting the whole time.